# Which template is responsible to display the products list in list page in magento 2

Tags: template, magento2.2, category-products

Which template is responsible to display each product in List page

Answer (score 2):

The main template (in default theme) is

> /public_html/m22.2.2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Above path is as per my server directories, so the correct path will be

> Magento_Installable_Directory/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now, I need product Id from the list.phtml to my custom JS using data attribute , How to I init my custom JS to list.phtml to get product ID

Comment: can you send the js code you wrote ? so i can check once

Comment: My doubt is , If I need id from list .phtml to my custom JS, then am I need to init my js to list.phtml? is this Mandatary to do ?

Comment: no its not mandatory you can  create an extension and then add the js file in the catalog_category_view.xml, let me add it to above answer or you can create a separate question

Comment: I have add code in list.phtml like data-id = "$product->getId"    and in Js  I get the id like     var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

Comment: But it says undefined

Comment: first problem is try to use $(this).attr('id'); but i think it will be ambiguous on the list page, so you have to add more selectors.

Comment: can you send the link of the page you are trying so i can see how to do it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73120/discussion-between-sri-and-sunil-verma).

Answer (score 1):

The default template for listing the products is this one `view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` from the `Magento_Catalog` module but there can be extensions that override this setting and use a different template.
Or the template can be changed by a theme you are using.
You can find out the real template by enabling the template path hints.

Comment: Now, I need product Id from the list.phtml to my custom JS using data attribute , How to I init my custom JS to list.phtml to get product ID ,